# JavaFx Project Error : Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "iconName" does not exist or is read-only

Tags: user-interface, javafx

so I'm trying to run this project and it displays this error eventhough I added the **fontawesomefx-8.2.jar**

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
 method     at
com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)   at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$159(LauncherImpl.java:182) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException:  file:/C:/Users/Yasmine%20Daly/Downloads/Gaming%20Dashboard/Gaming%20Dashboard/dist/run1549224879/Gaming%20Dashboard.jar!/gaming/dashboard/UI.fxml:23

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)  at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)    at gaming.dashboard.GamingDashboard.start(GamingDashboard.java:13)  at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$166(LauncherImpl.java:863)     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$179(PlatformImpl.java:326)     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$177(PlatformImpl.java:295)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$178(PlatformImpl.java:294)   at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.java:177)     ... 1 more Caused by: com.sun.javafx.fxml.PropertyNotFoundException: Property "iconName" does not exist or is read-only.    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:348)     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:325)     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:235)    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:767)   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)   at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)    ... 17 more Exception running application gaming.dashboard.GamingDashboard Java Result: 1
```

This is the UI file where the iconName exists and is underlined in red;

```
<FontAwesomeIcon iconName="MUSIC" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="134.0" size="1.5em" styleClass="sidebar-icon" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon iconName="GEAR" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="175.0" size="1.5em" styleClass="sidebar-icon" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon iconName="FILE" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="210.0" size="1.2em" styleClass="sidebar-icon" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon iconName="DASHBOARD" layoutX="33.0" layoutY="242.0" size="1.2em" styleClass="sidebar-icon" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon iconName="MUSIC" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="278.0" size="1.2em" styleClass="sidebar-icon" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon iconName="HEART" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="368.0" size="1.2em" styleClass="sidebar-icon" />
            <FontAwesomeIcon iconName="GEAR" layoutX="31.0" layoutY="399.0" size="1.5em" styleClass="sidebar-icon" />
```

Comment: Consider using modern software versions.

Comment: The code is flawless I just need to import some kind of jar or library so it can read the iconName

Comment: _code is flawless_ that's .. a bold statement ;) Do some research, make sure you have current versions of everything, when stuck come back with a [mcve] demonstrating what's wrong _exactly_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following is addressed, then I can use font awesome icons from FXML:

1. As it says, iconName is not a property of FontAwesomeIcon.
2. FontAwesomeIcon is an enum and not a node, so I don't know how you would use it from FXML.
3. There is a FontAwesomeIconView which is a node and has a property called glyphName and can be used instead.
4. Ensure recent versions, Java/JavaFX 17.0.2 and fontawesomefx  4.7.0-9.1.2.

Following the instructions here:

- [Load custom components in scenebuilder 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985646/load-custom-components-in-scenebuilder-17/70988201#70988201)

Using the following fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" spacing="10.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="MUSIC" size="1.5em" />
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="GEAR" size="1.5em" />
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="FILE" size="1.5em" />
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="DASHBOARD" size="1.5em" />
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="HEART" size="1.5em" />
   </children>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="10.0" left="10.0" right="10.0" top="10.0" />
   </padding>
</HBox>
```

Displays the following output in SceneBuilder:

[image: fonts]

To have this work in an app, you need to use a recent JDK and JavaFX, e.g. 17.0.2, as well as a recent FontAwesomeFX version and load the FXML into your app.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
    <artifactId>fontawesomefx-fontawesome</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0-9.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

See this question for an example of access via an app:

- [Unable to import certain classes in fontawesomefx after updating for Java 9 / Java 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61183565/unable-to-import-certain-classes-in-fontawesomefx-after-updating-for-java-9-ja)

[image: screenshot]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class FontApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(FontApplication.class.getResource("fonts.fxml"));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(fxmlLoader.load()));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```